# Measurement Protocol and Google Analytics: where to see cn (campaign name)

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

We're using the measurement protocol as `v=1&t=event&tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-X&cid=7fdf4bee-96c9-11e6-873f-120d450b74d3&ec=email&ea=open&cn=xxx&cs=yyy&cm=email&ci=zzz&dp=lll&dt=mmm&z=1479780958&el=nnn`.

From `Real Time->Events` we can easily see the event category (ec), event label (el) and event action (ea), but we fail to find other related info generated in the event like cn, cs, cm, ci, dp, dt, ...

Where/how can we access/see this information?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real-time reports are very limited.  You will have to wait the 24 hours and then look for them in the standard reports.   Normally part of source and medium.

Comment: OK. But even in Behavior->Events I can't see all the associated info, like Campaign ID... where/how to make a report a report can be made where all the information associated to an event is shown?

Comment: This might help https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/data-import-campaign#config